# Java generics - overriding an abstract method and having return type of the subclass

Tags: java, generics, types, return-value

I am trying to create a set up where a set of subclasses override a superclass. This superclass contains an abstract method - the return type of which would ideally be that of the object from which this method was called, such that it effectively behaves like this:

```
public abstract class SuperClass{
  public abstract SuperClass getSelf();
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
  @Override
  public SubClass getSelf(){
    return this;
  }
}
```

I am unsure if such a thing is possible, as I think return types always have to be the same in order for the override to work - however I have been thinking the answer, should one exist, lies somewhere along this line...

```
public abstract class SuperClass{
  public abstract <? extends SuperClass> getSelf();
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
  @Override
  public SubClass getSelf(){
    return this;
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

edit: added extends SuperClass to SubClass, duh

Comment: I don't see how you are going to use this. Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will work:

```
public abstract class SuperClass{
  public abstract SuperClass getSelf();
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
  @Override
  public SubClass getSelf(){
    return this;
  }
}
```

Notice I've added `extends SuperClass` to your `SubClass` definition. The return type of `getSelf` is referred to as a [covariant return type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type).

Comment: Ahh, of course I forgot to add extends SuperClass in the example though that certainly exists in my code...

That said, I was totally unaware that this already worked, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
public abstract class SuperClass<T extends SuperClass<?>> {
   public abstract T getSelf();
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass<SubClass> {
     public SubClass getSelf() {
         return this;
     }
}
```

I know it's quite repetitive and nothing bounds the type to be the same `SubClass` instance, because also `AnotherSubClass` would satisfy the bound, but at least it should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do it (Since JDK 1.5 there is this thing called covariant return types, where something like this is possible).

```
abstract class SuperClass<T extends SuperClass<T>>{
  public abstract T getSelf();
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass<SubClass> {
  public SubClass getSelf() { return this; }
}

public class Generics {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new SubClass().getSelf());
  }
}
```

Notice a similar class generic definition with Enum (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html)

See what happens behind the scenes (by using **javap SuperClass SubClass**):

```
class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    SubClass();
    public SubClass getSelf();
    public SuperClass getSelf();
}

abstract class SuperClass extends java.lang.Object{
    SuperClass();
    public abstract SuperClass getSelf();
}
```

Notice how the subclass method has a different return type, which is a subtype of the super method return type.

Btw, notice that `public SuperClass getSelf();` in class `SubClass` is actually a **synthetic** method.